# Unable to understand the function of key in sorting python lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

Sorry I can't understand what happens when key = key:

```
def key(x):
    return x[1]

a = [(1, 2), (3, 1), (5, 10), (11, -3)]
a.sort(key=key)
```

Comment: Sorted based on second element of each tuple.

Comment: Please make the title in English. Also, have you read the docs of `sort` to see what the `key=` parameter does?

Comment: Please be a little more precise about what you don't understand. Is the problem the sorting or how the argument is passed, or something else?

Comment: @Zelig74 if you are confused by key=key, then change the name of the function from `key` to `foo` (or any other name) and also change `a.sort(key=key)` to `a.sort(key=foo)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to first understand what is a keyword (named) argument:
https://treyhunner.com/2018/04/keyword-arguments-in-python/

Thereafter, you can see that for the `sort` method that belongs to the "`a`" list, you can see that it has a named argument of `key`: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort

The named argument `key` takes in a function in which the return value of that function will be used for sorting, which in your case, the `key` function defined at line 1 will use the second element of each tuple in the list for sorting.

i.e.

- first `key` on the LHS = named argument of `sort` method belonging to a list
- second `key` on the RHS = `key` function defined that returns a value to be used for sorting the list

Answer (score 1):

`sort` takes a keyword argument named `key`. With `a.sort(key=key)`, the function `key` is given for the keyword argument `key`. The sort function then applied the `key` function to every element in the list and then sorts the list by the result of this function call.

This may get less confusing when you rename the function, e.g. key_function.

```
def key_function(x):
    return x[1]

a = [(1, 2), (3, 1), (5, 10), (11, -3)]
a.sort(key=key_function)
```

The function returns the second element of the input value, so the value for `(1, 2)` will be `2` and for `(3, 1)` it will be `1`. These values will then determine how the tuples will be ordered other than how tuples will usually be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

The sort function, as chaooder says, needs a named parameter, which is "key". This is the parameter for the funtion, and it is always named "key".

When you call the function, you pass another function as the value for this parameter. You can set whatever name you want for this function.

The thing that is confusing you is that in your code the function you pass as value happens to have the same name as the parameter - "key".

I bet it would not confuse you as much if you have it like this:

def mykey(x):

return x[1]

a = [(1, 2), (3, 1), (5, 10), (11, -3)]

a.sort(key=mykey)

EDIT: user Talon answered the same while I was writing this one, so he beat me to it  :)